# Instance in upload_image function django framework

Tags: python, django

I have a issue in my code. I have a user model and it has a `profile_image` field with `ImageField`. I defined a `profileImageRoot()` function and equalized it to `upload_to` argument of `ImageField`. I have `profile_image_count` `IntegerField` and it increases 1 unit when image is uploaded in `profileImageRoot()`. I try save the value of profile_image_count on my database but `save()` method doesn't save. My source code: 
**User model:**

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, verbose_name="Username")
    email                   = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name="Email", help_text="Email you actively use")
    first_name              = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name               = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_of_birth           = models.DateField(blank=False)
    date_created            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    profile_image           = models.ImageField(upload_to=profileImageRoot)
    profile_image_count     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    spent_money             = models.FloatField(default=0)

    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified             = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth')

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
    
    def is_birthday(self):
        if timesince(self.date_of_birth, datetime.today()) == datetime(day=0, month=0):
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def verify(self):
        self.is_verified = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

**profileImageRoot():**

```py
def profileImageRoot(instance, filename):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    ext = filename.split(".")[-1]
    user.profile_image_count += 1
    print(user.profile_image_count)
    user.save()
    return f"{user.username}/profile_image/{user.profile_image_count}.{ext}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because your original `instance` contains the old value for `profile_image_count`. Since the saving process first needs to call `profileImageRoot()` and then write data from `instance` to database, your increased value for `profile_image_count` is overriden with the old value.

Try to also increase `instance.profile_image_count` in `profileImageRoot()`.

This, however, seems like a poor solution overall. If you want some ordering in file names for profile images consider using timestamps or alike. Besides there's no guarantee that `profileImageRoot()` will be called just once per `save()` call, or that it won't be called unless new image is uploaded.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I will look for timestamps. Thank you again